# HTML5 getUserMedia is not working with scientific microscopy camera Lumenera

Tags: javascript, browser, camera, html5-video

I am using microscopy camera Lumenera INFINITY1-2 (https://www.lumenera.com/infinity1-2.html) and from the camera description it tells that it can be integrated into 3rd party software packages using TWAIN support. I try to capture image from web page using HTML5 but it gives me error. 
I also tried to check video streaming with Adobe Flash but camera stream is not displayed properly and captured images is quite broken (in fact it is empty)

I checked camera's drivers and they all installed and works. Native camera application also captures images well.

Question, is it possible to capture images in the web browser from the microscopy camera like that? It is being recognized by browser as a device but video stream is not working.

Please see below script (code is getting from here https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md)

Thank you in advance

````
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            // [1] GET ALL THE HTML ELEMENTS
            var video = document.getElementById("vid-show"),
                canvas = document.getElementById("vid-canvas"),
                take = document.getElementById("vid-take");
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    // [3] SHOW VIDEO STREAM ON VIDEO TAG
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                    take.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        // Create snapshot from video
                        var draw = document.createElement("canvas");
                        draw.width = video.videoWidth;
                        draw.height = video.videoHeight;
                        var context2D = draw.getContext("2d");
                        context2D.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
                        // Output as file
                        var anchor = document.createElement("a");
                        anchor.href = draw.toDataURL("image/png");
                        anchor.download = "webcam.png";
                        anchor.innerHTML = "Click to download";
                        canvas.innerHTML = "";
                        canvas.appendChild(anchor);
                        var imageBase64 = draw.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
                        document.getElementById("hdn_ImageByte").setAttribute("value", imageBase64);
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(err)
                    document.getElementById("vid-controls").innerHTML = "Please enable access and attach a camera";
                });
        });
    </script>```
````